# How to get rid of Lohit Hindi and set a different default font in right to left complex script

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, keyboard-layout, rtl

I use multiple languages with libreoffice. I have genome ubuntu 12.04 installed. When i change the keyboard layout from English to Pashto or Persian the standard font is changed to Lohit Hindi. This font does not support many of the characters in Pashto and/or has problems with some the characters.

How do I change the settings so that when when I press (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>) to change the keyboard layout the font changes to a pre-specified font like Bahij Nassim or Arial rather than Lohit Hindi.

Answer (score 1):

I also have *Lohit Hindi* as "Basic Fonts (Western)" of my LibreOffice under Ubuntu 12.04. I am not sure how it became so. I had to:

1. Go to **Tools → Options → LibreOfiice Writer → Basic Fonts (Western)**
2. Change all "Basic fonts" from *Lohit Hindi* to, say, *Liberation Sans*.